# ParseException error code getting lost when being sent to react-native layer

Tags: java, android, react-native, parse-server

I've been testing handling expired sessions with parse and trying to catch the error and send it to the react-native layer but I was having issues with the code coming back as 'EUNSPECIFIED' as opposed to '200' which wasn't happening on iOS my solution was the function below for handling errors but if anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void handleError(Promise promise, Exception error) {
    if (error instanceof  ParseException) {
        ParseException exception = (ParseException) error;
        promise.reject(Integer.toString(exception.getCode()), exception.getMessage(), exception.getCause());
    }
    else promise.reject(error);
}
```